# Set different color to parent menu item after hovering over submenu

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a menu with submenu using only css and html.

I'm trying to make the main menu get some color when mouse is over it..

And keep this change while mouse is over submenu..

All I can do now is to set the same color os submenu..

Here is what I'm trying to do:

[image: FOTO]

My code:

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">

   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

   <li>
      <a href="#">Institucional</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Nonononono</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Nonononono</a></li></li>
         <li><a href="#">Nonononono</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#nav{
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:right;
    width:100%;
    font-size:13px;
}

#nav li{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
}

#nav a{
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    color:#666;
    text-decoration:none;
    //background:white;
}
#nav a:hover{
    color:yellow;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#D93600;
}

#nav ul{
    //border:1px solid black;
    border-top:0;
    border-right:0;
    background:#D93600;
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         3px 3px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
#nav ul li{
    padding-top:1px; /* Introducing a padding between the li and the a give the illusion spaced items */
    float:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FF7040;
    margin-right:0px;
}
#nav ul a{
    white-space:nowrap; /* Stop text wrapping and creating multi-line dropdown items */
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul{ /* Display the dropdown on hover */
    left:0; /* Bring back on-screen when needed */
}
#nav li:hover a{ /* These create persistent hover states, meaning the top-most link stays 'hovered' even when your cursor has moved down the list. */
    //background:#D93600;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul a{ /* The persistent hover state does however create a global style for links even before they're hovered. Here we undo these effects. */
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:12px;
}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover{ /* Here we define the most explicit hover states--what happens when you hover each individual link. */
    background:#FFBE13;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just apply `:hover` effect for full `li` element

```css
#nav > li:hover {
  background-color: #D93600;
  color: yellow;
}
#nav > li:hover a {
  color: yellow;
}
/* rest of code */

#nav {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#nav li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}
#nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none;
  //background:white;

}
#nav a:hover {
  color: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #D93600;
}
#nav ul {
  //border:1px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  background: #D93600;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
#nav ul li {
  padding-top: 1px;
  /* Introducing a padding between the li and the a give the illusion spaced items */
  float: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FF7040;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
#nav ul a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Stop text wrapping and creating multi-line dropdown items */
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
  /* Display the dropdown on hover */
  left: 0;
  /* Bring back on-screen when needed */
}
#nav li:hover a {
  /* These create persistent hover states, meaning the top-most link stays 'hovered' even when your cursor has moved down the list. */
  //background:#D93600;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li:hover ul a {
  /* The persistent hover state does however create a global style for links even before they're hovered. Here we undo these effects. */
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover {
  /* Here we define the most explicit hover states--what happens when you hover each individual link. */
  background: #FFBE13;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">

  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">Institucional</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sobre o CCOCF</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Assosiação de Amigos do CCOCF</a>
      </li>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Projetos da Casa</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this its very simple

```
 <ul id="nav">
   <li class="primary"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li class="primary">
      <a href="#">Institucional</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Nonononono</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Nonononono</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Nonononono</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>

    #nav .primary:hover a {
    color: #FFBE13;
    background: #D93600;
   }
```

just add the above class to the li and two lines of css

Comment: Very simple but took me an hour to solve this.. sometimes I feel that I'm stupid. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

to make the Parent menu highlighted on hovering you should write following CSS rules.

```
#nav li:hover {
  background:#f00;
}
```

To make the Parent menu text white you should write following code

```
#menu li:hover a {
  color:#ffff;
}
```

if you want to check above code please check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/g5jL7xs1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/4tb3236w/), setted color for parent if it is active.

```
$('#nav ul li').hover(
    function() {    
        $(this).parents('li').addClass('subColor');
    },      
    function() {
        $(this).parents('li').removeClass('subColor');
    }        
);
```